# Stripe Radar rule when a customer attempts multiple cards with multiple names

Tags: stripe-payments

Reviewing my chargebacks, I often encounter this kind of scenario: "the guy tried 5 cards with 5 different names, and yet Stripe approved his 6th attempt?!". Seems like an obvious fraudulent pattern that Stripe Radar should detect and block...

Is there a way to configure Stripe Radar so to block payments if "a given session / IP / email attempted more than X payments with X different names in a given period of time"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Rule Reference](https://stripe.com/docs/radar/rules/reference) and [your Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/settings/radar/rules) I think this 3 conditions can achieve nearest to what you want.

[image]

Comment: Stripe's customer support told me something similar. So it's not exactly it, but it's the nearest, yes. Thanks!